# How do I run Samba 1.0 under 18.04?

Tags: networking, 18.04, samba

I upgraded my Dell XPS13DE from 14.04 to 18.04 after some updates broke my audio and touchpad.  Under 18.04, I lost access to my NAS drive and my network printer is slow.  Zoom will not install because Samba doesn't work.  My router only operates with Samba 1.0 and I don't want to fool with passwords, anyway.  I have had two people, one that is a Linux sys admin try to help and none of the suggestions have helped.  I have removed and reinstalled all Samba components and tried various edits of samba.conf, but that did not cure the problem.  Please fix/help me fix Samba.  I've been fooling with this off and on for about a year.

Comment: " I have had two people, one that is a Linux sys admin try to help and none of the suggestions have helped. "  all the answers you will get are going to include those your 2 people tried. It is custom to actually list those suggestions they tried.  My answer is a generic one that (acc. to my documentation ;) ) worked for me.

Comment: You almost certainly need [_SMB 1_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block#SMB_/_CIFS_/_SMB1), not Samba 1. The current version 4 of Samba should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

Add `ntlm auth = ntlmv1-permitted`  to `/etc/samba/smb.conf` in the `[global]` section and restart Samba with `sudo service smbd restart`.

And to anyone needing this: Samba 1 is disabled for security reasons in Ubuntu 18.04 and onwards for good reasons. So only use this to extract what you need and ditch the hardware.

Comment: Depends. If he's not using WiFi he could theoretically have a secure LAN for which he doesn't have to care.